# Как внедрить(java.util.Scanner)?

Tags: java

Как можно задействовать (java.util.Scanner) в коде ?

```
public class Seasons {
 static String[] winterGoods;
 static String[] springGoods;
 static String[] summerGoods;
 static String[] autumnGoods;
 static String month;
 static String [] arrSeason;
 static int pos;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     winterGoods = new String[]{"Шуба", "Пуховик", "Парка"};
     springGoods = new String[]{"Пальто", "Ветровка", "Комбинезон"};
     summerGoods = new String[]{"Футболка", "Поло", "Шорты"};
     autumnGoods = new String[]{"Куртка", "Гольф", "Плащ"};
     month = "Декабрь";
     month = month.trim().toLowerCase();

     checkMonth();
     if (arrSeason != null) {
         showData(arrSeason);
     } else {
         System.out.println("Что-то не так!");
     }
 }

 private static void checkMonth() {
     switch (month) {
         case "декабрь": case "январь": case "февраль":
             arrSeason = winterGoods;
             break;
         case "март": case "апрель": case "май":
             arrSeason = springGoods;
             break;
         case "июнь": case "июль": case "август":
             arrSeason = summerGoods;
             break;
         case "сентябрь": case "октябрь": case "ноябрь":
             arrSeason = autumnGoods;
             break;
         default:
             System.out.println("Не определено!");
     }
 }

 private static void showData(String[] arrGoods) {
     pos = 0;
     System.out.println("Поставка на " + month + ":");
     for (String product : arrGoods) {
         pos++;
         System.out.printf("%d. %s %n", pos, product);
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Опишите задачу, для чего вы хотите использовать сканер. Что не получилось, когда вы пробовали его использовать?

Comment: Он работает, но как сделать так чтобы user вводил месяц и оно потом выводило информацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    month = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
    winterGoods = new String[]{"Шуба", "Пуховик", "Парка"};
    springGoods = new String[]{"Пальто", "Ветровка", "Комбинезон"};
    summerGoods = new String[]{"Футболка", "Поло", "Шорты"};
    autumnGoods = new String[]{"Куртка", "Гольф", "Плащ"};

    checkMonth();
    if (arrSeason != null) {
        showData(arrSeason);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Что-то не так!");
    }
```

[nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: У меня есть массивы с товарами к каждому месяцу. Что нужно сделать для того, чтобы когда user ввел месяц в Scanner, то ему вывело информацию о товарах (заданный массив) на этот месяц ? Пример: Июнь = "Футболка", "Поло", "Шорты"

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        month = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
        winterGoods = new String[]{"Шуба", "Пуховик", "Парка"};
        ....

Comment: Это нужно удалить: month = "Декабрь";
     month = month.trim().toLowerCase();

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: На здоровье! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Мало репутации у меня для лайка

Comment: Ну это дело наживное :-)

Comment: На следующей строке после month = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase(); нужно прописать System.out.println("Введите месяц: ");

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110539/discussion-between-evgeniivolkov-and-best-vine-video-miliodas).